# How to properly render nested comments in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm trying to make nested comments work properly in a rails 5 app and running into a lot of difficulty.

I'm building a question and answer site, and I have an Acomment model in which there are comments that belong to answers, and then there are comments that belong to other comments:

```
class Acomment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Acomment", optional: true
  has_many :replies,
           class_name: "Acomment", foreign_key: :parent_id, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I want to display all comments, and then all replies to comments, and replies to replies, etc.  But I can't figure out how to make the nesting work properly.

In my view, inside an each loop, I'm rendering the `_comment.html.erb` partial:

```
<% answer.acomments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= render :partial=>"comment", :object=>comment %>
<% end %>
```

Then, inside my `_comment.html.erb` partial, I'm displaying the comments, a reply link, and then rendering a partial for the replies to comments:

```
<div>
  <%= comment.body %>
  <%= link_to "Reply", new_acomment_path(:parent_id => comment, :answer_id => comment.answer) if comment.parent_id.blank? %>

  <%= render partial: "reply", collection: comment.replies %>
</div>
```

Here's the `_reply.html.erb` partial:

```
<%= reply.body %>
<%= link_to "Reply", new_acomment_path(:parent_id => reply, :answer_id => reply.answer) %>
```

I'm running into two problems:

1) When I render the first partial, not only does it render the comments, but it also renders the replies at the same time (since they are also comments).

2) When I render the second partial (the replies), they are not nested within the comments where they are supposed to.  Everything is out of order.

EDIT:
I expect to see this:

```
Comment 1 
  Comment on Comment 1 
    Comment on Comment on Comment 1 
Comment 2
```

But instead this is what I'm seeing:

```
Comment 1 
Comment on Comment 1 
Comment 2 
Comment on Comment 1 
Comment on Comment on Comment 1 
Comment on Comment on Comment 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of the second issue? What do you observe, what do you expect to see instead? I'm not picturing what's going wrong. Have you looked at the SQL generated by `comment.replies` to make sure you're getting back what you expect? When you're in the rails console and fetch a comment do you get what you expect when you look at `comment.replies`?

Comment: I expect to see this:
Comment 1
  Comment on Comment 1
     Comment on Comment on Comment 1
Comment 2

But instead this is what I'm seeing:

Comment 1 
Comment on Comment 1
Comment 2
Comment on Comment 1 
Comment on Comment on Comment 1
Comment on Comment on Comment 1

But in the rails console, I am seeing what I would expect. When I do comment.replies I see the appropriate replies, and when I do comment.parent I see the appropriate parent.

Comment: Ok, that's super hard to understand as code-formatting in comments is pretty awful. Can you please edit your question and give like example-data and what you'd expect it to appear as? Then you can indent the replies on the "how it should look" section and it'll be clearer to me :)

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't realize the formatting wouldn't be maintained. I just updated my question and hope that helps.  Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: NP - we all have to learn that at some point... ;)

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer to add an explanation of what's probably going on for point 2 (and why). Also a bugfix+explanation for what I think is happening with pablo's answer (and would be for mine too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part of your question, you'll probably need some scopes that help you distinguish between "parent comments" (ie comments that aren't replies) and "child comments" (replies).

something like:

```
class Acomment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Acomment", optional: true
  has_many :replies, class_name: "Acomment", foreign_key: :parent_id, dependent: :destroy

  scope :is_parent, where(parent_id: nil)
  scope :is_child, where("parent_id IS NOT NULL")
end
```

You can use these eg below to render only parents in the main loop... with the intention each parent will render its own children.

```
<% answer.acomments.is_parent.each do |comment| %>
    <%= render :partial=>"comment", :object=>comment %>
<% end %>
```

WRT your second question - I'll need a bit more info - I'll ask in comments above.

After:

So... My guess at what's happening is: you're just getting all the comments (as you mentioned) and they're being displayed in the outer loop (instead of just the parents being displayed int he outer loop) and they're in that order because that's the database-order for the comments.

Nothing is actually being displayed in the inner loop due to a default naming convention in partials.

If you use `collection` in a partial - Rails will feed each item into the partial... and then name the local variable after the name of the partial. In this case, you are trying to render a partial named "reply", but passing in a set of comments... so the partial is going to look for a variable called "reply".

I'd recommend you just reuse the same "comment" partial that you already use and instead render it this way:

```
<div>
  <%= comment.body %>
  <%= link_to "Reply", new_acomment_path(:parent_id => comment, :answer_id => comment.answer) if comment.parent_id.blank? %>

  <%= render partial: "comment", collection: comment.replies %>
</div>
```

It will be recursive (just like Pablo's suggestion) and thus render comment threads by indenting for every set of sub-comments.

Looking at your conversation with pablo... it's possible that `parents` is a bad name for a scope... it sounds like it might be interfering with a ruby-method named the same thing that traverses up the class hierarchy... so perhaps it's a bad name - as such I'll rename the scope.

Answer (score 5):

As Taryn wrote, you first need to filter the comments with no parent_id, which means they are first level comments to an answer.

views/answers/show.html.erb

```
<%= @answer.text %>
<h4>Comments</h4>
<% @answer.acomments.parents.each do |comment| %>
  <%= render :partial=>"comment", locals: { comment: comment } %>
<% end %>
```

Then you need a recursive approach:

views/acomments/_comment.html.erb

```
<div>
  <%= comment.body %>
  <%= link_to "Reply", new_acomment_path(:parent_id => comment, :answer_id => comment.answer) if comment.parent_id.blank? %>

  <% comment.replies.each do |reply|
    <%= render :partial => "comment", locals: { comment: reply } %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

You need to provide some indentation so that it is clear the hierarchy between comments.

Comment: When I do this I get undefined method 'body for Object:Class. The error is coming in the Show view on the comment.body line.

Comment: You have an acomments table, don’t you?  What is the column name that contains the comment? I thought it was body. Replace by the correct field name. Maybe ‘comment.comment’ or ‘comment.text’.

Comment: Sorry. I thought the error was in the comment partial. I have not included body in the show view.

Comment: Right, I included comment.body in my partial as you have above and that is when I'm getting the error. @answer.acomments.parents.each does not seem to work properly here.

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me the field name for the comment in your database?. This is what you should use instead of body. Why do you say ‘....parents.each’ is not work? Do you get errors or does it not return and comment?

Comment: The field name in the database is body, so that part is correct. I'm saying the parents.each part is not working because instead of operating on each specific object, it is trying to apply the 'body' method to Object:Class, based on the error message.

Comment: Are you calling the partial with ‘comment: comment’ in show and ‘comment: reply’ in the partial? Or are your using object: comment?  My answer does not use body.

Comment: Sorry. My answer does not use ‘object’

Comment: I'm calling the partial with comment: comment in show and comment:reply in the partial, same code as you have in your answer. It's giving a NoMethodError with undefined method 'body' for Object:Class, and the error is referencing the comment.body line. In the rails console when I call answer.comments.parents it does not return a collection, instead it just returns [Object]

Comment: Ok. You didn´t post your Answer model. Can you put it? Does it `has_many :acomments`?